# Update d3 graph with new data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, mapping, gis

I am trying to update a d3 graph when I click on a County on a map. Instead of updating the existing chart, a new graph is created each time. Any ideas of how to rectify this? Code is here: https://github.com/careyshan/d3-graphUpgade
Thanks

This is the part of the code that I am having difficulty with:

```
on("click", function(d,i){

              if(document.getElementById('linechart').childNodes===null){
                console.log("Working")
                dataNew = data.filter(function( obj ) {
                  return obj.County == d.properties.NAME_TAG;
                    console.log(data);
                });

                dataNew.sort(function(a,b){
                // Turn your strings into dates, and then subtract them
                // to get a value that is either negative, positive, or zero.
                return b.date - a.date;
                });
                for (var i=1; i<dataNew.length;i++){
                dataSel.push(dataNew[i]);
                }
          }else if(document.getElementById('linechart').childNodes!=null){
                //console.log("check")
                dataNew = data.filter(function( obj ) {
                  return obj.County == d.properties.NAME_TAG;
                });

                dataNew.sort(function(a,b){
                // Turn your strings into dates, and then subtract them
                // to get a value that is either negative, positive, or zero.
                return b.date - a.date;
                });
                for (var i=1; i<dataNew.length;i++){
                dataSel.push(dataNew[i]);
                }
              }
              linechart(dataNew);
              console.log(dataNew);
          });
```

Answer (score 3):

A new graph is created each time because on every call to the function `linechart()` you are appending a new graph (an svg element) to the body of the page.

This is the snippet from your code which appends a new graph each time.

```
  // append the svg obgect to the body of the page
  // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
  // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("id","linechart")
      .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

If you want to update the same chart, just modify your `linechart()` function to refer to the same svg element. You can achieve this by declaring a global variable for the svg element and use it in your `linechart()` method like below:

```
  // If graph is not there, create it
  if(!svg) {
      // append the svg object to the body of the page
      //appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
      // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
      svg= d3.select("body").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
          .attr("id","linechart")
          .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
  }
```

Note: Declare the svg as a global variable (may be at the starting of the script tag):

```
var svg;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have implemented this and it adds the new data to the graph now - thanks. How do I make it update the old data with the new data rather than add the new data to the graph on each click? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean, you don't want to see the old data on each click? @user1655130

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to remove old data on each click!